# Can't locate object method "find_md5" via package "DBM::Deep::Engine::Sector::Scalar"

Tags: perl

Does any one know why am getting this error ?

```
Can't locate object method "find_md5" via package "DBM::Deep::Engine::Sector::Scalar" at /u/xref/xref.10/bin/../lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/DBM/Deep/Engine.pm line 1599
```

Please let me know how to get Rid of this.

Answer (score 2):

Because `$o->find_md5` was called where `$o` is the string `DBM::Deep::Engine::Sector::Scalar` or an object of class DBM::Deep::Engine::Sector::Scalar, yet that class doesn't have a method named `find_md5`.

(DBM::Deep::Engine::Sector::Scalar doesn't even seem to exist in newer version of the DBM::Deep distribution, so upgrading DBM::Deep would be a good start.)